# How to replace Mongo query parameters with Node.js variables

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDb get request with Node.js. I would like to replace two of the values in the query with variables (req.query.pauseTime). How do I do that. The code works with numbers, but not with ordinary variables.

I have tried

```
let min = req.query.pauseTime -120;
let max = req.query.pauseTime + 120;
```

and then tried to replace {"$gte": 6, "$lte": 12} with {"$gte": min, "$lte": max}

When using 6 and 12 I get back

```
 [ { _id: 6, count: 5 },
  { _id: 7, count: 8 },
  { _id: 9, count: 8 },
  { _id: 10, count: 2 },
  { _id: 12, count: 8 },
  { _id: 8, count: 7 },
  { _id: 11, count: 8 } ]
```

when replacing with variables I get an empty array.

in the following code:

```
videoCommentsRoutes.route('/count').get(function (req, res) {
    VideoComments.aggregate([ {"$match": {"pauseTime": {"$gte": 6, "$lte": 12} } },
        {"$group" : {_id:"$pauseTime", count:{$sum:1}}}
    ]).exec(function (err, commCount){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            res.json(commCount);
        }
    });
});
```

So, how can I replace the number 6 and 12 with the variables?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this , use the same query with pauseTimeQuery variable

```
videoCommentsRoutes.route('/count').get(function (req, res) {
     let min = Number(req.query.pauseTime) - 120;
     let max = Number(req.query.pauseTime) + 120;

     const pauseTimeQuery = {
         "$gte": Number(min), 
         "$lte": Number(max)
       }    

VideoComments.aggregate([ {"$match": {"pauseTime": pauseTimeQuery } },
        {"$group" : {_id:"$pauseTime", count:{$sum:1}}}
    ]).exec(function (err, commCount){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            res.json(commCount);
        }
    });
});
}
```